# Explaining higher intersection multiplicities using deformation of the curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Consider the intersection at $(0,0)$ of the curves defined by the quadratic equations
$Y = X^2$ and $X^2 + (Y - 1/2)^2 = (1/2)^2$.  Using the definition of intersection multiplicity in terms of local rings, it's clear that the intersection multiplicity is 4.  Is it also possible to argue for this multiplicity using a deformation of the curves such that the single point of intersection becomes four distinct points of transversal intersection?  The method is referred to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_number#Intersection_multiplicities_for_plane_curves):

> Intersection multiplicity can also be realised as the number of distinct intersections that exist if the curves are perturbed slightly ...".

Comment: Note that the 2 curves you gave intersects transversally in 4 distinct points.

Comment: Here's a computation to back up the fact that the intersection at the origin actually has multiplicity $1$. $I=(X-Y^2, X^2+(Y-1)^2-1) = (X-Y^2,Y(Y^3+Y-2))$. In the local ring at $P=(0,0)$, $Y^3+Y-2$ is invertible, so $Y\in I_P$ and thus $X\in I_P$.

Comment: Apologies, I "simplified" the curves when posting and in so doing, changed the multiplicity.  I'll update the question now to use the original curves.

Answer (score 1):

Deform the equation of the circle by to $X^2 + (Y - 1/2)^2 = (1/2)^2 + \epsilon^2$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ (this increases the circle radius slightly).  This decomposes what was previously the single point of intersection $(0,0)$ into four distinct points of transversal intersection:

$$ (\sqrt \epsilon, \epsilon),\ (-\sqrt \epsilon, \epsilon),\ (\sqrt \epsilon i, -\epsilon),\ (-\sqrt \epsilon i, -\epsilon)$$.

These points of course converge to $(0,0)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for Desperado and @Karl Kroningfeld for their comments to the question which revealed the answer to me, as well as the necessary modification of the question.